Non-Analytical Differentiable Hamiltonian Function in Neural Networks
Im writing a study on this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.01563v1
Its by Sam Greydanus et al. And they discovered that by using Neural Networks to predict the Hamiltonian (total energy of a system) rather than the symplectic gradient directly they are creating models that conserves energy well.
I have a few questions and angles i would like to explore in my study:
First, i stumbled upon an interview of the Father of Neural Networks Geoffrey Hintons where he explains how the most impactful part of neural networks are their parallel nature. They compute in parallell, and not in a sequential order. He emphasised the importance of this, since sequential computing suffers inevitably from accumulating errors.
I found this quite interesting because this insight can be drawn to Hamiltonian Neural Networks and why neural networks are well suited for these type of problems. The goal of HNNs is to properly predict the evolution of a system over extended periods of time.
The problem with traditional numerical methods, in my understanding, is their sequential nature which is not really explored in the paper by Greydanus. For chaotic systems we dont really have an analytical solution when it comes to computing the gradients of the Hamiltonian, and traditionally numerical schemes has to be employed => thereby creating accumulated "energy drift" since the result of integration reveleas energy is not conserved. For finite differences the approximation error at any step could be O(h) which will accumulate and essentially create a "false" ground truth for the next differentation step.
This is where i think Neural Networks should be more explored as a computation tool. Firstly it can compute a whole time evolution of a system at once in parallell and can localize errors to certain neurons, alleviating the accumulation of errors from one part of the series. Also it can compute gradients excactly with autodiff, using the chain rule.
This brings me to my next question. Regarding chaotic systems with non-analytical differentiable hamiltonians, like the 3 body problem. We then have to create labels using finite differences, and that would render the HNN useless right? So in general if we have to use finite differences to create labels then its no point in using neural networks. And if we can differentiate the hamiltonian and create gradients analytically why include a neural network in the mix. Cant we just use a symplectic integrator on the solved gradients?
Any insights would be highly appreciated, also im just an engineering student so i could be well off here.
